# Inserting a list of value into SQLite column from python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Say I have a list of following values:

```
listA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want to put each value of this list in a column named `formatteddate` in my SQLite database using executemany command rather than loop through the entire list and inserting each value separately.

I know how to do it if I had multiple columns of data to insert. For instance, if I had to insert listA,listB,listC then I could create a tuple like `(listA[i],listB[i],listC[i])`. Is it possible to insert one list of values without a loop. Also assume the insert values are integers.

UPDATE:
Based on the answer provided I tried the following code:

```py
def excutemanySQLCodewithTask(sqlcommand,task,databasefilename):
    # create a database connection
    conn = create_connection(databasefilename)
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.executemany(sqlcommand,[(i,) for i in task])
        return cur.lastrowid

tempStorage = [19750328, 19750330, 19750401, 19750402, 19750404, 19750406, 19751024, 19751025, 19751028, 19751030]

excutemanySQLCodewithTask("""UPDATE myTable SET formatteddate = (?) ;""",tempStorage,databasefilename)
```

It still takes too long (roughly 10 hours). I have 150,000 items in tempStorage. I tried INSERT INTO and that was slow as well. It seems like it isn't possible to make a list of tuple of integers.

Comment: Have you got any code to show you have attempted this?

Comment: @EcSync Updated it with code.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do.  Do you want to insert a new row for each value?  And if so, is there only one column named 'values' in the table?  If there are other columns, do they accept null?  OR do you want to update existing rows with these new values?  If so, you need a primary key value paired with each value to update correct.  Also, you specify a column named `values` in the explanation, but your code shows a column called `formatteddate`.   Altogether is it very unclear what you intend to do.

Comment: Although this is not an answer to fix the overall problem, be aware that running an UPDATE command without a WHERE clause to limit the rows will update ALL rows in the table. The code you have is essentially updating ALL table rows with one value, then replacing ALL formatteddate columns with another value, then repeating over and over about 150,000 times... so that in the end, all rows have same values, the last value in the list.  (All other values in the list are overwritten.)

Comment: @CPerkins I have a list in Python with integers(they are formatted dates). I already have a table with multiple columns and all rows have some value in them. I added a new column to the table named `formatteddate`. This new column has null values. I want to put the values in the list into the new column named `formatteddate`. Thanks for pointing out some mistakes in the above code but that has been fixed. I just forgot to fix it here. First, let me ask you this: which would be better INSERT or UPDATE? I assume INSERT because there are no existing values in that column. (Cont'd)

Comment: @CPerkins In the past when I have inserted multiple column values, I was able to create a list of tuples and do executemany. That saved a lot of time. I can't seem to do that while inserting a single column. It seems I can't make a list of tuple of integers. I have found other ways that can improve performance. For instance, you can turn off PRAGMA JOURNAL_MODE to OFF. That could save time. I was hoping that there was a way to INSERT multiple rows at the same time but only for one column.

Comment: Do you know what setting journal mode to off does?  Is savings in time really worth the risk?

Comment: @CPerkins It will disable transaction rollback but I have backups of the database. The INSERT is a one time thing.

Comment: If you have fundamental question like whether to use INSERT or UPDATE, I highly recommend going through a SQL primer/tutorial.  The key concept is a table contains rows of data.  Yes there are columns, but a row is really the fundamental set of values since column values in a single row are meant to be intrinsically related.  INSERT creates a new row.  If you have existing rows, even with a new column, you still need to UPDATE existing rows by setting values in columns **of each row**.

Comment: This is why I mentioned the need for a primary key paired with each value.  It's not just like a spreadsheet where you can "paste" a column of data and have it implicitly related to the rows without having to actually define the row.  You are required to specify which row you are updating or else it will update EVERY ROW in the table for a single UPDATE statement.  Reread my comment about the WHERE condition, etc.  Something like `UPDATE myTable SET formatteddate = (?) WHERE id = (?)` and pass it a list of tuples like `[(19750328, 1), (19750330, 2), ...]` where 1, 2, ... etc. are the row keys.

Comment: @CPerkins I had tried INSERT before and I found what you said to be true. I said INSERT before because I just don't have enough confidence with SQL. I am actually running an UPDATE statement on 900,000 rows right now. It is taking forever. It has been running for past 50 hours.

Comment: @CPerkins Just saw your second comment. I do have primary key. I am using that as well but I did it the wrong way. `"""UPDATE """+tablename+""" SET formatteddate = ? WHERE id = """ + str(gids[i]) + """ ;"""` and I am running it using execute command. Thank you so much for pointing that out. I didn't think of creating a tuple with formatteddate and primary key. As I said, I am still a beginner when it comes to SQL.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being a beginner, but it's usually best to get a sample working and understand it very well and test it before trying to update so many rows.  The entire purpose of using SQL parameters `?` like with the formattedate is to create a **pre-compiled command** that you then just pass data.  By regenerating the SQL text each time you are essentially defeating that mechanism.  Define the SQL string once, then pass data to the same command.

Comment: FYI:  I would gladly have created a concise, well formatted answer but I perceived that there was more details missing and some misunderstanding.  Nothing against anyone else, by the knee-jerk answer you got was not so helpful this time.  I hope my comments altogether help you create a good solution.

Comment: @CPerkins There was certainly a misunderstanding because of how I worded my question. Original post lacked details. I'll do better in the future. Thanks again. You probably saved me several days.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, you need a list of tuples. So you can do:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (?)", [(a,) for a in listA])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried it your way but it is still too slow. It seems like it is inserting one value at a time.

Comment: It **is** inserting one value at a time.  executemany() reruns the same SQL statement for each value passed individually for the single SQL parameter `?`.

Comment: In the sql, "INSERT..." statement, what column is ListA being inserted to?